# Webstorm Javascript: Jump to "usages"

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I just switched to Mac, from PC, and I'm trying to make my Webstorm settings match my old PC settings... though I can't remember one setting.

I don't remember the wording, and I don't think it was "usages". When developing Javascript, I can use `CTRL + B` to go to declaration, but I had `CTRL + SHIFT + B` which jumped between usages of the function your cursor was on... The opposite of `CTRL + B` you could say...

I've searched, and searched for it, but with no luck...

Do you know what it's called or where to find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It helped writing it, and saying it out loud. I just remebered it. The PC short-cut is `CTRL + F7` and the name is `Find Usages in File`.